# What information does the abs(normalized_image - normalized_quantised_image) carry?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, quantization, normalization, information-hiding

Given a grayscale image X2

[image: X2]

And its (under)quantised version with 3 bits depth X3

[image: X3]

What information does the `abs(X2_normalized - X3_normalized)` carry?
As an example the following image X5 generated with the code below

```
X2norm= X2-min(X2(:)); X2norm = X2norm / max(X2norm(:));
X3norm= X3-min(X3(:)); X3norm = X3norm / max(X3norm(:));
X5 = abs(X2norm - X3norm);
image5=figure;imagesc(X5);title('image 5');
saveas(image5,'image5.jpg');
```

[image: X5]

Comment: I would suggest that you exchange the word "quantified" for the word "quantised".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your image is a $K$ bits depth image, and the quantized version is a $3$ bits version, pixels of the difference image, represent $(K-3)$ **least** significant bits of pixels of the original image. It means it completely is similar to original image in darker parts and completely masks the brighter parts.

Comment: Because the two images are normalized independently, this probably doesn’t hold.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is probable you are right, I'll check again.

Comment: @Cris Luengo I could not find it, I am interested to know. would you give some hints?